# How to Check if people are emedding my site content

Tags: x-frame-options

Hi I am planning to implement X-frame-options security header and want to know which sites it will cause any issues who have embedded my site content.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't easy with x-frame-options but can be done with Content-Security-Policy. You don't really need x-frame-options anymore now that IE is retired as all relevant browsers now understand Content-Security-Policy.

If you just want to know without actually blocking any sites you can start with Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only, but if you don't care if they are blocked, you can use Content-Security-Policy. You can define it like this:

```
Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: frame-ancestors 'self'; report-uri <url to report service>;
```

The frame-ancestors directive restricts which sites can frame your site and the value 'self' is the same as "sameorigin" in x-frame-options.

The report-uri directive defines where violation reports should be sent. Alternatively you can use the report-to directive. For details on this see e.g. https://content-security-policy.com/ and for a report service you can use https://report-uri.com/ which has a free tier for small report volumes.

Note that the reports will in most cases not give you the host or URL of the site that tried to frame your site. This is due to privacy concerns as URLs could include authentication or personal information. But it will tell you if your site is presented in a frame.

If you want to understand which sites are actually framing your site you can include the referrer somewhere in the policy. Add the host of the referrer to a directive which isn't currently in use, and make sure not to include the full URL:

```
Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: frame-ancestors 'self'; frame-src <host of referrer>; report-uri <url to report service>;
```

The reports will now include the host of the framing sites if your reporting service shows you the full policy being violated.